# Finding tan inverse in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to find the angle made by the line joining a point with the x-axis with the x-axis. So in effect I'm trying to find plain old tan inverse.
Here's the code I'm using in Python 3

```
angle_with_x_axis = math.atan(y_from_centre / x_from_centre)
```

I'm feeding in the `point(1,1)` as `y_from_centre` and `x_from_centre` and I get

```
0.7853981633974483
```

My expected result is 45, but naturally. 
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: [That is 45 degrees](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=0.7853981633974483+radians+in+degrees&oq=0.7853981633974483+radians+in+degrees&aqs=chrome..69i57.2147j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). It's been returned in radians.

Comment: I'm embarassed already.

Comment: Aside: you should consider `atan2` rather than `atan(y/x)`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`math` uses radians. For degrees use `math.degrees`:

```
>>> math.degrees(math.atan(1))
45.0
```

Answer (score 8):

The [math](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html) module operates in radians. 0.785 radians is 45 degrees. From the docs:

> math.atan(x)
>
> Return the arc tangent of x, in radians.

Answer (score 2):

The [`math.atan()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.atan) function - and many of the other functions in the [`math`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html) module - return their results in radians. The documentation clearly states this:

> Return the arc tangent of x, **in radians**.

<sub>(emphasis mine)</sub>

The `math` module does however provide a way to convert radians to degrees, and visa versa:

```
>>> import math
>>> math.degrees(math.atan(1))
45.0
>>> 
>>> math.radians(45.0)
0.7853981633974483
>>>
```

You can also create a helper function to wrap this logic:

```
>>> def atan_in_degress(x):
...     return math.degrees(math.atan(x))
... 
>>> atan_in_degress(1)
45.0
>>> atan_in_degress(2)
63.43494882292202
>>>
```